# How do I use rqt_plot to subscribe to std_msgs

Tags: ros, std-msgs, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do have an Array from `#include "std_msgs/Float64MultiArray.h"` and it is constituted as followed:

```
layout: 
  dim: []
  data_offset: 0
data: [0.0073274714, -0.019451106, -0.009992006]
---
```

Now, if I use rqt_plot it does not show any data when selecting the topic. I cannot figure out why? If I hover over the `+` button in the GUI it just says no plottable fields.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226584/how-do-i-use-rqt_plot-to-subscribe-to-std_msgs/) by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on ROS Answers with karma: 748 on 2016-02-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-14**:
Are you sure that empty `dim` field is correct? I wouldn't be surprised if `rqt_plot` cannot work with `*Array` msgs that have no valid dimensions associated with them.

**Comment by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on 2016-02-14**:
how do I fill in the dim field? What i do so far is

```
      arr.data.clear();
    arr.data.push_back( x);
    arr.data.push_back( y);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After having a look at [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/60194/oddity-in-rxplot/?answer=60203#post-id-60203) I figured it out as `/Float64MultiArray/data[0]` fo the first entry of the array with `data` being the array-name. 
[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) with karma: 748 on 2016-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1